# How to resize window in pygame (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, resize, pygame2

I'm making a game and I want to be able to resize the window, so I set the screen to `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)`. I have a function call `resize()` that updates the positions of the all the images too.

```
def resize():
    width, height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
    cookie_surface = pygame.image.load('/xxx/xxx/xxximages/cookie.png')
    cookie_surface = pygame.transform.scale(cookie_surface, (275, 275))
    cookie_rect = cookie_surface.get_rect(center = (width/2, height/2))

#auto clicker image
    auto_clicker = pygame.image.load('xxx/xxx/xxx/images/mouse_cursor.png')
    auto_clicker = pygame.transform.scale(auto_clicker, (480,360))
    auto_clicker_rect = auto_clicker.get_rect(topleft = (width-350, -100))

#farm image
    farm_img = pygame.image.load('/xx/xxx/xxx/images/farm.png')
    farm_img = pygame.transform.scale(farm_img, (480,360))
    farm_rect = farm_img.get_rect(topleft = (width-350, -85))

#save button image
    save_surface = pygame.image.load('/xxx/xxx/xxx/images/save.png')
    save_surface = pygame.transform.scale(save_surface, (480,360))
    save_rect = save_surface.get_rect(center = (130, height+78))

#bg
    bg = pygame.image.load("/xxx/xxx/xxx/images/bg.jpg")
    bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (width, height))
```

When I run the code, I get this error:
`pygame.error: Window surface is invalid, please call SDL_GetWindowSurface() to get a new surface`

What am I doing wrong? (If you want all my code let me know)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's difficult to guess what you've done wrong. My guess is that you've not recreated your primary surface using `pygame.display.set_mode(…)`. If you're using the development version of Pygame 2, then you won't need to recreate your primary surface.

Here's an example that shows how to resize a window:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
image = pygame.Surface((120, 100), pygame.SRCALPHA)
image.fill(pygame.color.Color("royalblue"))
center_pos = (width // 2, height // 2)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            width, height = event.dict["size"]
            # recreate screen object required for pygame version 1
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            # TODO: resize image if needed
            center_pos = (width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center=center_pos))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using pygame 2.0.0.dev6, I'll try some more things ig

Comment: If you're using development versions, `dev6` is a little old. You can use use `pip install pygame --pre` to grab the latest pre-release, which in this case is `dev16`.